# How to find the number of factors by different Ids using dplyr?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I am trying to converge my data by organization ids. To do so, I need to find how many different domains there are for each id (excluding **NAs**). I can't figure out how to do it in R using **dplyr** package. Any help is appreciated.

This is something similar to what my data looks like.

| id | domain |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ca |
| 1 | ca |
| 1 | com |
| 1 | na |
| 1 | com |
| 2 | org |
| 2 | na |
| 2 | ca |
| 3 | org |
| 3 | ca |
| 3 | com |
| 3 | net |

What I want is to get the following output:

| id | count_domain |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

I don't want to do this in excel, but if that's the more efficient approach, I am also open to answers in excel.

PS: My actual data contains much more rows and types of domain, so writing 'if statements' is not something that would be feasible.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your data has `NA` and not literal string `"na"`, then you could try

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("id    domain
1   ca
1   ca
1   com
1   NA
1   com
2   org
2   NA
2   ca
3   org
3   ca
3   com
3   net") 

df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(count_domain = sum(!is.na(unique(domain))))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id count_domain
  <dbl>        <int>
1     1            2
2     2            2
3     3            4
```

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for the answer. I also want to extend upon this, what to do if I have to repeat this procedure with other columns and then save the output to a table? I keep getting errors if I put two summarise commands.

Comment: @KhurramAhmed Can you edit your question with the data and error that you encounter? The code should work on any `character` column with `NA`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this can be achieved with the following solution in Excel (assuming that your data is stored in the range `A:B`; and na should not count according to your sample data).

First, enter the following formula in, e.g., cell `D2`, to create the unique set of IDs (this could also be specified more dynamically, if needed for e.g., varying lengths of the data):

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A13)
```

To compute the number of domains, enter the following formula in cell `E2`:

```
=SUM(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,(A:A=D2)*(B:B<>"na"),"")))>0))
```